# Amount of reputation until next privelege

Tags: feature-request

Why is it that the "next privilege" bar shows the amount of privilege required for your next privilege to even be your next privilege? It makes it look as though I am a lot closer to attaining the next privilege than I really am. Take my own for example:

[image: Privileges]

I know I already have 1,000 rep! Can't the bar just display the amount I need out of 250? I feel as though it would be a lot more useful in performing its task if it functioned this way.

Comment: Congrats on the 1K!  I think this is a network wide thing.

Comment: If you want to suggest a modification, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list) is the place to do it. And good work on 1000 rep!

Comment: Thanks @NicolauSakerNeto.  That's exactly what I would have recommended.

Comment: [My suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256223/amount-of-reputation-until-next-privelege) didn't go over very well! Oh well...

Comment: @Martin I think, since the issue is unhandled on meta.SE, I believe a [tag:status-bydesign] or [tag:status-declined] may be in order.

Answer (score -1):

I think that bar is working perfectly. Though It can be made more clearer If we keep it like [E.L.L. S.E.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

[image]

---

BTW congratulation for reaching 1k :)

Comment: What ringo is talking about, applied to your case, is asking why your example isn't 5/25 instead of 105/125. The last milestone was 100 and the next is 125, and you've gotten 5 out of the 25 rep necessary for the next milestone, which corresponds to 20% of the next step complete